# How to prove the following determinant identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-physics

This problem is relevant to the [spin operator matrix elements](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2603v1) in the quantum 1D XY model.

For any even integer $N$, define two sets $$K_+=\left\{\frac{(2m+1)\pi}{N}|m=-\frac{N}{2},-\frac{N}{2}+1,...,\frac{N}{2}-1\right\}$$ and $$K_-=\left\{\frac{2m\pi}{N}|m=-\frac{N}{2},-\frac{N}{2}+1,...,\frac{N}{2}-1\right\}.$$ 
For any integer $1\leq n\leq (N-1)$, if $n$=even (odd), we choose $n$ distinct numbers $k_1,k_2,...,k_n$ from set $K_+$ ($K_-$), and choose $n+1$ distinct numbers $k'_1,k'_2,...,k'_{n+1}$ from set $K_-$ ($K_+$). Prove that:
\begin{align}\sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2<...<j_{n+1}\leq N}\det\left(
                                 \begin{array}{ccc}
                                   e^{-ik'_1j_1} & ... & e^{-ik'_1j_{n+1}} \\
                                   .. & ..  & ..  \\
                                   e^{-ik'_{n+1}j_1} & ... & e^{-ik'_{n+1}j_{n+1}}\\
                                 \end{array}
                               \right)\det \left(
                                             \begin{array}{cccc}
                                               1 & e^{ik_1j_1} & ... & e^{ik_nj_1} \\
                                               -1 & e^{ik_1j_2} & ... & e^{ik_nj_2} \\
                                               .. & .. & .. & ..  \\
                                               (-1)^n & e^{ik_1j_{n+1}} & .. & e^{ik_nj_{n+1}} \\
                                             \end{array}
                                           \right)=2^nN\delta\left(\sum^{n+1}_{j=1} k'_j,\sum^n_{i=1} k_i\right)\frac{\prod_{i>i'}(e^{ik_i}-e^{ik_{i'}})\prod_{j>j'}(e^{-ik'_j}-e^{-ik'_{j'}})}{\prod^n_{i=1}\prod^{n+1}_{j=1}(1-e^{i(k'_j-k_i)})}.\end{align}

The Cauchy determinant and [Cauchy–Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) seem highly relevant, but I have no idea how to treat the sum '$\sum_{j_1<j_2<...<j_{n+1}}$', i.e., how to split it into a summation over $n$ variables '$\sum_{j_1<j_2<...<j_{n}}$' (leading to the Cauchy determinant) and a single sum '$\sum^N_{l=1}$' (leading to the $\delta$-function).

-*Update*: This problem has recently been solve in the following paper by using a fermionic approach:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00682

Comment: Um, you are allowed to apply the Cauchy-Binet formula with $n$ replaced by $n+1$ if you want... and it looks like this will solve your problem, or at least reduce it to a significantly simpler one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Prof. Tao. But the first column of the second matrix is always a constant vector $(1,-1,...,(-1)^n)^T$ for all configurations $j_1<j_2<...<j_{n+1}$. No such $N\times (n+1)$ $B$-matrix can fit in the Cauchy-Binet formula. I believe the $\delta-$function results from the sum '$\sum^N_{j_{n+1}=1}$', since $1\leq j_1<j_2<...<j_{n+1}\leq N$ can be replaced by $1\leq j_1\leq j_2\leq...\leq j_{n+1}\leq N$.